# draw a horizontal dashed line in Jfreechart gantt

Tags: jfreechart, gantt-chart

Does any one know how it possible to move/draw dashed line at specific position in Gantt chart?
For example i have chart that look like this:

[Link to image](http://imageshack.us/f/834/81188251.png/)

and it hard to see where is tasks 1 bars and where task 2 bars and where task 3.

If it possible to draw horizontal lines not in line of 1,2,3 but after whole series to make clear visual separator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want one of the [`org.jfree.chart.annotations`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html) such as `CategoryLineAnnotation`.